# Android: ArrayAdapter showing only one item even though the ListView isn't placed in a ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to programming in Android. I encountered a problem where I need to print three items in a list View, yet getting only a single item. In many answers, I saw that ListView should't be placed in a ScrollView, I have rechecked my code, and that isn't actually the problem.

```
package com.apress.gerber.reminder;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RemindersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView mListView;
private String records[] = {"first record", "second record", "third record"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reminders_list_view);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.reminders_row,
            R.id.row_text,
            records);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
}
```

Xml files:-
Reminders_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/row_tab"
        class="android.view.View"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/reminder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_reminders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.apress.gerber.reminder.RemindersActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/reminders_list_view"
    android:layout_width="373dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/reminders_row"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What actually is the error occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to extend your class with `ArrayAdapter` and customize `getView` method but you want to use your customized layout than your `TextView` must have id `android:id="@android:id/text1"` Or you can use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in your ArrayAdapter like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        records);
mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Also for your `ListView`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thanks.. it was a very silly mistake which I did, the ListView, I couldn't catch that.